# ashx file being called on every postback of server control for jqgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in asp .net webforms page along with many other server controls in the form.
To populate the jqgrid i am using an ashx file which does a Database call and returns the data. The data is successfully binding to the grid.

**Issue**
When a postback happens due to a server control like a dropdown or a button click, the jqgrid always calls the ashx file to fetch data from the database.

How can I prevent jqgrid to fetch data on postback due to server controls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the full postback and use Ajax calls,try to  put the controls you want to be updated by the postback inside an update panel.